# Directly storing apps in SD Card

Tags: rooting, adb, internal-storage, external-sd, insufficient-memory

So I bought an 'Swees' Android phone recently, with ~150mb Internal storage + 4gb External SD Card.

I downloaded Android SDK manager on my mac, installed necessary packages and ran the 'adb' file in Terminal.

I set Default Storage Locaction to '2', (i.e. External Storage).

This was a success.

I have moved all my installed apps to SD Card (which I couldn't do before).

However, it seems I still have ~95% of Internal Memory used up.

When I download an app from the Play store it installs directly into the SD Card, which is what I want.

But when I install some apps (big file sizes) it will return an error, "insufficient storage space available".

I have >3.5GB available on my SD card.

Does the file have to be downloaded before it's installed on the SD card. And does it keep the downloaded file in Internal Memory?

I have no idea why else this is happening.

Comment: I am afraid the device has poor internal storage and "big apps" check for /data which is a folder inside internal memory. So a solution can be downloading files on computer then adb install -s yourapp.apk (s stands for sdcard).

Comment: If /data free size is bellow apk size (reported by google play) actually it won't let you install even let's say you have 1 gb internal memory but only 400 mb free and the "big app" has 500 mb (for example). So play with adb